# Как сделать так, чтобы не обновлялась страница при отправки формы с помощью ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Написал всё, так, чтобы не обновлялась страница, а закрывался один popup и после отправки открывался другой. Но меня почему-то перекидывает на пустой файл mail.php. Подскажите, что я неправильно написал?

HTML:

```
    <section class="modal">
    <div class="container">
            <div id="modal__wrapper">
                <div class="modal__overlay" id="modal__overlay"></div>
                    <div class="modal__window">
                        <a href="#" class="modal__close" id="modal__close"></a>
                        <div class="modal__content">
                            <h3 class="modal__title">
                                Заказать обратный звонок
                            </h3>
                            <form method="post" action="mail.php" class="modal__form" id="modal__form">
                                <input type="text" name="firstName" class="modal__item" required placeholder="Имя">
                                <input type="email" name="mail" class="modal__item"  placeholder="E-mail">
                                <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" class="modal__item" required placeholder="Телефон">
                                <button class="modal__btn" id="modal__btn" data-submit>
                                        Заказать звонок
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__successful" id="modal__successful">
            <div class="modal__overlay" id="modal__overlay-ty"></div>
            <div class="modal__successful-window">
                <h3 class="modal__successful-title">
                    Отлично! Мы скоро вам перезвоним.
                </h3>
                <a href="#" class="modal__btn_two ghost__btn" id="modal__close-ty">Закрыть</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
//Валидация и отправка формы

$('[data-submit]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
})
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function (value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
);

    // Функция валидации и вывода сообщений
    function valEl(el) {
        el.validate({
            rules: {
                phoneNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    regex: '^([\+]+)*[0-9\x20\x28\x29\-]{5,20}$'
                },
                firstName: {
                    required: true
                },
                eMail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                phoneNumber: {
                    required: 'Поле обязательно для заполнения',
                    regex: 'Телефон может содержать символы + - ()'
                },
                firstName: {
                    required: 'Поле обязательно для заполнения',
                },
                eMail: {
                    required: 'Поле обязательно для заполнения',
                    email: 'Неверный формат E-mail'
                }
            },
            // Начинаем проверку id="" формы
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var $form = $(form);
            var $formId = $(form).attr('id');
            switch ($formId) {
                case 'modal__form':
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: $form.attr('action'),
                        data: $form.serialize()
                    })
                        .done(function () {
                            console.log('Success');
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            console.log('Fail');
                        })
                        .always(function () {
                            console.log('Always');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#modal__successful').addClass('active');

                            }, 1100);
                            $('#modal__successful').on('click', function(e) {
                                $('#modal__successful').removeClass('active');
                                $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
                            });
                            $('#modal__wrapper').removeClass('active');
                        });
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: поставьте кнопке тип `type=button` и всё

Comment: А  метод `submitHandler` будет по умолчанию отменять сабмит формы?

Answer (score 0):

Первые 4 строчки. Вы отменяете отправку формы по клику на кнопку, а потом следом отправляете форму через `.submit`. Вам нужно совсем отменить отправку формы, а все данные передавать AJAX запросом на сервер.